# Entangled electrons where one is converted to energy (and neither measured)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, quantum-entanglement

I watched an interesting "Great Courses" video about how entangled electrons could be put into separate boxes and separated by a distance.  When one is measured, the other immediately collapses into a state. Say that neither is measured, but a button is pushed on one of the boxes that causes its electron to be converted to energy (such as by a nuclear explosion, etc.).  What would happen to the other "entangled" electron?  In a private email with a trusted source, I was told, "...if the disruption was independent of spin, the remaining electron will still be in the superposed state."
So, I see three possibilities.  1) The superposed state is lost. 2) The electron collapses to a state because of the disruption to its twin. 3) The entanglement remains, without the electron collapsing to a state. In this last case, what happens if the electron is then measured? (Presumable the "energy" due to the other electron must "collapse", which sounds strange to say.)
I would be interested to hear what someone with more knowledge than me has to say about this. I am just an interested amateur with little knowledge of the subject.

Comment: I removed my answer because it was a bad example. However the answer stands, entanglement remains. The electron just gets entangled with the "energy"/photons or whatever decay products the other one left (assuming that while manipulating the other electron you did not perform a measurement).

Comment: electrons cannot "be converted to energy"

Comment: Hi Maurico.  Thanks for you reply that the electron "gets entangled with the 'energy'/photons or whatever decay products the other one left."  So what happens to the energy when we subsequently measure the entangled electron?  The electron would collapse into a state, but what does the "collapse" of the energy do or mean, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, if you convert one of the electrons to energy (e.g. by colliding it with an anti-electron) the entanglement just gets transferred to the photons (the energy) emitted by the annihilation. If the electron is in a superposition of spin states, the photons will be in a corresponding superposition of polarisations. Angular momentum is conserved, so the spin just gets passed on to the reaction products.

A more interesting question (and one which I think is more in the spirit of what I think you *really wanted to know*) is to ask what happens if we destroy one of the particles by dropping it in a black hole and waiting until it hits the singularity. This is related to the famous black hole information paradox. And in this case, the answer is that nobody knows. It is still an area of active research.

For the particle remaining outside the black hole, the answer depends on what interpretation of quantum mechanics you susbscribe to. The Everett Interpretation (sometimes called the Many Worlds Interpretation) is local, so no effects from the future can propagate to the past, and so nothing that happens to the electron inside the black hole can affect the one still outside in any way. The electron remains in superposition. For interpretations where wavefunction collapse can travel faster than light and backwards in time, it depends on whether whatever happens at the singularity constitutes an 'observation' for the purposes of collapse, which is usually ill-defined.

For the joint state to be a combination of two sub-system states, and for one of the subsystems to be erased presumably constitutes a 'change' of the joint state. If the two particles maintain a faster-than-light long-distance *physical* connection, maintaining 'knowledge' about each other, then it is hard to see how erasing part of the wavefunction doesn't result in a collapse-like change to all of its parts. However, it is not at all clear that this is how the connection works in collapse interpretations.

The trouble is that 'joint' states with space-like separated parts don't make much sense - we can take many different space-like slices through spacetime, and call the slice through the wavefunction along each one a 'joint state'. We define a joint state looking something like $\left|\psi_a\right>\times\left|\psi_b\right>$ but $\left|\psi_a\right>$ and $\left|\psi_b\right>$ are functions of time. How do we assign corresponding times to each of these space-like separated parts? The state at either location at a particular point in time isn't just coupled to what's happening to the other at the 'same' time, but to what's happening all along its worldline.

This is further complicated in the black hole's case, because the singularity is never in the past lightcone of any observer. It can be in the future, or in the 'elsewhere', but not the past. So it is not even clear that the electron dropped into the black hole has been destroyed yet. In some reference frames it has, in other reference frames it hasn't. So it's arguable that the first electron is always still there, in *some* reference frames, and so there never need be a collapse arising from its destruction.

However, there are no observable consequences of either alternative - whether it collapses or not. 'Interpretations' of quantum mechanics all make exactly the same predictions about observations, and are thus experimentally indistinguishable. We cannot observe how faster-than-light collapses truly propagate in reality, so if there is a collapse we'll probably never know the answer for sure. The Everett Interpretation does at least give a definite answer to the question.

--

As I mentioned, this is still an area of active research, and even the top names in physics (at the Stephen Hawking level) struggle to understand what is really happening here. I'm not in that league, so take everything I say here with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer!